# How to make a status command in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to make a command that changes my bots status, all i know is that `client.user.setActivity('STATUS');` sets the bots status to "STATUS" but im having trouble getting the status to set from a commands arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more elements to the status than just a string

```js
client.user.setActivity({
    name: `Actual text here`,
    type: '', // 1 of the 4 below here
});

// 'WATCHING'
// 'LISTENING'
// 'PLAYING'
// 'STREAMING'
```

Depending on how you have your command set up depends on how it is executed, but without a code example, I have way too many choices on how to initiate this.